# Java script not calling in html

Tags: javascript, html

The java script code which has the two functions display() and DisplaySessionTimeout().

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var sessionTimeout = 1800;

            function DisplaySessionTimeout()
            {
                window.history.go(+1);
                sessionTimeout = sessionTimeout - 1;
                //document.getElementById("val").innerHTML=sessionTimeout;

                //if session is not less than 0
                if (sessionTimeout >= 0)
                {
                    //call the function again after 1 minute delay

                    window.setTimeout("DisplaySessionTimeout()", 1000);
                } else
                {
                    //show message box
                    //document.getElementById("val").innerHTML="TIME OUT";
                    alert("Your current Session is over.");
                    setTimeout(document.form1.sub.click());
                }
            }


            

                    var milisec = 0
            var seconds = 30
            document.form1.d2.value = '30'

            function display()
            {
                if (milisec <= 0) {
                    milisec = 60
                    seconds -= 1
                }
                if (seconds <= -1) {
                    milisec = 0
                    seconds += 1
                } else
                    milisec -= 1
                document.form1.d2.value = seconds + "M : " + milisec + " S"
                setTimeout("display()", 1000)
            }

         
        </script>
```

```html
  <body onLoad="javascript:display();DisplaySessionTimeout();">
```

The body section of the html calls the java script,but it does not work.Why did it not work? Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: Remove `javascript:` in the event caller: `<body onload="display();DisplaySessionTimeout();">`

Comment: What are the HTML comments for?

Comment: Try removing HTML comments in JS code

Comment: You've got HTML comments in the middle of your code which render it invalid. Look at the JS console in your browser's developer tools. The error messages it reports are useful.

Comment: removed comments,still doesnot work.

Comment: Where is the form? put it up.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude tried that . Still error.

Comment: `Still error` what does it means? You need to share the complete problem. IF you have an error, show us what error is.

Comment: Otherwise, this should be closed as offtopic (read the help center for more info)

Comment: posted the entire code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited few things like removed html-comment statements from Js, remove `JavaScript:` from the `onload`, etc.

Comments in html : `<!-- comment -->`

Comments in JS :

```
//comment single line
/*
   Comment multi-line
*/
```

I think this should fix it.

```js
var sessionTimeout = 1800;

function DisplaySessionTimeout() {
  window.history.go(+1);
  sessionTimeout = sessionTimeout - 1;
  //document.getElementById("val").innerHTML=sessionTimeout;

  //if session is not less than 0
  if (sessionTimeout >= 0) {
    //call the function again after 1 minute delay

    window.setTimeout("DisplaySessionTimeout()", 1000);
  } else {
    //show message box
    //document.getElementById("val").innerHTML="TIME OUT";
    alert("Your current Session is over.");
    setTimeout(document.form1.sub.click());
  }
}



// 
var milisec = 0
var seconds = 30
document.form1.d2.value = '30'

function display() {
  if (milisec <= 0) {
    milisec = 60
    seconds -= 1
  }
  if (seconds <= -1) {
    milisec = 0
    seconds += 1
  } else
    milisec -= 1
  document.form1.d2.value = seconds + "M : " + milisec + " S"
  setTimeout("display()", 1000)
}
```

```html
<body onload="display();DisplaySessionTimeout();">
```

If you are still getting the error post the full code so that I can check.

Comment: this code will show a box but the required timer is missing.it just shows a box.

Comment: Do you just want a JS timer?

Comment: i wanted a JS timer.Thanks. i shall try that out

Comment: In the JS (of that code), the last line a `deadline` variable is set which is currently 15 days, you may change it as necessary.

Comment: Suppose i am using all the java script,css and html in one html file,how do i link the java script?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112272/discussion-between-alphaprogrammer-and-ani-menon).